# How to replace MultipartEntity with MultipartEntityBuilder on Android?

Tags: android

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.150.101:8080/TDIDP/ServletImagen");
File file = new File("C:\\pw\\proyectos\\TDIDP\\a.png");

MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/png");
mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);

httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
if (resEntity != null) {
  System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
}
if (resEntity != null) {
  resEntity.consumeContent();
}

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

I have this code that sends images to a Servlet, but the problem is that now MultipartEntitiy is not available for Android since it is obsolete, how can I use MultiPartEntityBuilder to do a multipar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I use MultiPartEntityBuilder to do a multipart.

`HttpClient` is not supported any more in sdk 23, if you use it, you need to work around much. You have to use `URLConnection`
You can see `MultipartUtility` in this link https://github.com/RecastAI/SDK-Android/blob/master/src/main/java/ai/recast/sdk_android/MultipartUtility.java.